# Why does this PHP setcookie() argument not set a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have this PHP

`setcookie('hello', '0', 0, '/389732/');`

Why when I run it does it not set a cookie?

I printed the value of `$_COOKIE['hello']` out immediately after and it puts out an error because it does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

[setcookie documentation](http://us.php.net/setcookie) spells this out:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on **the next page load** with the $_COOKIE ...

Edit: it might be tempting to manually insert that cookie into `$_COOKIE` yourself, but keep in mind that some frameworks helpfully parse `$_COOKIE` into other data structures on startup and will not see such hackish changes.

Comment: If you don't understand why, you should look into how the HTTP protocol works- it's a request/response protocol. You're sending a response to tell the browser to set a cookie, and then on the next request it makes, it will send back the cookie value.

Answer (score 1):

$_COOKIE gets populated when the script first runs.  setcookie puts the cookie info in a queue that gets turned into a header when the page returns to the browser.

When the browser requests a new page, it sends the cookie information back to your server and the $_COOKIE variable will be populated.

Comment: Ok... but on page reload the `$_COOKIE['hello']` still doesn't print

Answer (score 0):

Because the $_COOKIE is the content of the cookie when the php was called.